# Putting another website along with Zend website

Tags: php, facebook, zend-framework, file-get-contents

I am working with a website built (not by me) on Zend framework.

I have made a small website (for a Facebook app) built on simple html with custom php (no Facebook API used), which, if put in *public/* folder (so that it can be reached via *www.main_site.com/my_small_site*), does not work (I get **Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration**).

The **php.ini** on the website, however, contains **allow_url_fopen = on**, so my guess is that all my php files should be simply put somewhere in the *application/* folder, instead of the *public/* folder.
The websites don't use shared files, they are independent. And purchasing another hosting is an expensive option.
I am absolutely new to Zend, and learning how to make my own controllers/views will consume too much time, so this is the last option to consider.

How can I solve this problem?

- Access *.php* located in *application/* from *public/my_small_site/index.html*? (is it possible without touching the main website's *public/index.php*?)
- Create a new view and put my small website there? (how can I make it accessible from the web?)
- Still consider new hosting/subdomain options?
- Any other solutions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public/` is the correct place to put your Facebook app. The error doesn't lie - are you 100% sure the php.ini file you checked is the one being used? I'd suggest you create a phpinfo file as explained here https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/764/How+can+I+create+a+phpinfo.php+page%3F#gs - this will let you view the configuration PHP is using. See what `allow_url_fopen` is set to there. If it is set to 'off', there might be a different php.ini file you need to change.

Otherwise, contact your host.

Comment: The .ini file shown in phpinfo is /usr/lib/php5/php.ini, which contains allow_url_fopen = Off. However, this option is set to On in the host settings (I guess it uses another file which is located in the root folder (which contains public/, application/ etc)). So, this is an issue with the host or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "host settings" - you might need to ask your hosting provider about this. The settings shown in phpinfo are the settings PHP is using, so these host settings aren't being used.

Comment: By "host settings" I meant the only set of PHP settings that my hosting provider allows me to configure, so... I don't see a possibility to change the php.ini that is actually being used.
Still, I will try to contact my provider, thanks for the answer)

Comment: Managed to get around this problem by using cURL instead of file_get_contents :)